# how to find user defined inspected property errors in interface builder?

Tags: ios, swift

I have the following error, and I know which storyboard it is coming from. How does one search for a uibutton/view inside interface builder?

```
Failed to set (top) user defined inspected property on (UILabel): [<UILabel 0x7fd2cd3205f0> setValue:forUndefinedKey:]: this class is not key value coding-compliant for the key top.
```

Comment: The problem is that a UILabel has no `top` property.

Comment: Command+F and type in whatever you want to search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend just setting a breakpoint in xcode and then casting the memory address to the correct type and printing it.

```
po (UILabel *)0x137d4d060
```

Don't put a space between the parenthesis and the hex value or it won't work properly. it's picky about white space.